# How to deconstruct an object and exclude a property?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-2016

I want to deconstruct an object and exclude a property.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
 let x = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
 let y = {...x};
 delete y.c;
 store.setState(y);
```

I found an article about ES7 which states there is a new feature to exclude properties. So the above would be written like this:

```
 let x = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
 store.setState({c, ...x});
```

https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90

The above doesn't work in Angular 7 and I get the following error:

```
error TS2663: Cannot find name 'c'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.c'?
```

I'm currently running TypeScript 3.1.6, and my *tsconfig.app.json* file looks like this.

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "module": "es2015",
        "types": []
    },
    "exclude": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Here is the parent file.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I think the issue is that the line `"lib": ["es2017"]` is for ES6.

What can I do to enable this ES7 feature and will it break targeting ES5 as the compiled output from TypeScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply update your line - `let y = {c, ...x};` with `const {c, ...noC} = x;`. So your code would be -

```js
const x = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
const {c, ...noC} = x;

console.log(noC);
```

**Suggestion:** It's a good practice to make `x` constant, if you are not going to update it later.

Comment: My holiday gift :)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, if the object's property is not a valid JavaScript identifier, e.g. 'x-http-header', just map it to a valid identifier. Example `const {'x-http-header':omit, ...include} = headers`.

Comment: Within a function the object key has to be wrapped in square brackets: `const omit = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj:T, key:K): Omit<T,K> => {const {[key]:omit, ...keep} = obj; return keep}`

Answer (score 7):

Order sholud be like this

```
let { c, ...y} = x;
```